# How can I use JXBrowser to upload whole Directory, not just multiple files

Tags: jxbrowser

Chrome supported the non-standard 'webkitdirectory' property for html 'input' element since 2011, and it works great. [codepen sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVzQaP)

I would like to run jxbrower. Its latest version as of Mon, 21 May, 2018 was based on Chromium 64.0.3282.24 (Dec 12, 2017), yet it does not support this property.

What am I missing ? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
      <div>
        <label for="uploaddir" style="width: 600px; background: #ccc;border: 1px solid black;">Choose directory to upload</label>
        <input type="file" id="uploaddir" webkitdirectory onchange="updateImageDisplay()" style="opacity:0;">
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul id="listing"></ul>
      </div>
</html>

<script>
    var input = document.getElementById('uploaddir');
    var output = document.getElementById('listing');

    function updateImageDisplay() {
      while (output.firstChild) {
        output.removeChild(output.firstChild);
      }
      var curFiles = input.files;
      for (let i = 0; i < curFiles.length; i++) {
        const item = document.createElement('li');
        item.innerHTML = `${curFiles[i].webkitRelativePath} (${curFiles[i].size} bytes)`;
        output.appendChild(item);
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser can upload the whole directory. What can be wrong in your case is the file chooser dialog that is not configured to chose directories.

I make a simple example to demonstrate how you could configure file chooser dialog in swing:

```
browser.setDialogHandler(new DefaultDialogHandler(view) {
    @Override
    public CloseStatus onFileChooser(FileChooserParams params) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(view) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            params.setSelectedFiles(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            return CloseStatus.OK;
        }
        return CloseStatus.CANCEL;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. We use javafx instead of swing. So would the equivalent to JFileChooser be DirectoryChooser ?

Comment: As far as I know, JavaFX DirectoryChooser doesn't have the option to choose files and directories

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitry. This is the javafx implementation analogous to this [swing](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013089-file-upload) example. Note the following two crucial observations.

1. Need 'Runnable runnable' or it throws this error: 'SEVERE: The DialogHandler.onFileChooser() method has thrown exception: 
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on the event thread only; currentThread = Browser Events Thread'.
2. Need 'FutureTask' to BLOCK the Event(?) thread until the user clicks OK in the directory browser. Otherwise, onFileChooser will return CloseStatus.CANCEL immediately. By the time params.setSelectedFiles is called , it's already too late, and any  uploaded files will not be received by the angular controller.

> ```
> private String path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\temp\\foo";
>
> private void setDirectoryListener(Stage primaryStage) {
>
>     browser.setDialogHandler(new DefaultDialogHandler(view) {
>         @Override
>         public CloseStatus onFileChooser(FileChooserParams params) {
>             final AtomicReference<CloseStatus> status = new AtomicReference<>(
>                 CloseStatus.CANCEL);
>
>             Runnable runnable = () -> {
>                 if (params.getMode() == FileChooserMode.OpenFolder) {
>                     DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
>                     directoryChooser.setTitle("Open Resource Folder");
>                     directoryChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(path));
>                     File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);
>                     if (selectedDirectory != null) { // in case of CANCEL
>                         List<File> allFiles = new ArrayList<>();
>                         getOnlyFiles(selectedDirectory, allFiles);
>
>                    params.setSelectedFiles(allFiles.toArray(new File[0]));
>                         status.set(CloseStatus.OK);
>                     }
>                 }
>             };
>
>             FutureTask<Void> task = new FutureTask<>(runnable, null);
>             Platform.runLater(task);
>
>             try {
>                 task.get();
>             }
>             catch (InterruptedException interrupt) {
>                 throw new Error("Unexpected interruption");
>             }
>             catch (ExecutionException exc) {
>                 throw new RuntimeException(exc);
>             }
>
>             return status.get();
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> private static void getOnlyFiles(File file, List<File> files {
>     if (file.isFile()) {
>         System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
>         files.add(file);
>     }
>     File[] children = file.listFiles();
>     if (children == null)
>         return;
>     for (File child : children) {
>         getOnlyFiles(child, files);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

```
INPUT:    
`<input id="dirinput1" type="file" webkitdirectory ngf-select="uploadDir($files)/>`

OUTPUT:

C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp\foo\bar\csv.png
C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp\foo\bar\import_OQ_Manual.txt
C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp\foo\mz.PNG
C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp\foo\test.txt
```